# R - Extracting values from other rows

Tags: r, return-value, data-cleaning

As suggested by the title, I would like to extract values from other rows.

In particular, as an example please consider the following dataset:

```
id.in.group <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
trial <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
subject <- c("s7","s11","s3","s6","s9","s4","s12","s10","s1","s8","s2","s5","s5","s9","s6","s10","s1","s3","s4","s7","s2","s8","s12","s11","s5","s3","s9","s12","s11","s10","s1","s6","s7","s4","s2","s8")

df <- data.frame(group, id.in.group, trial, subject)

df$other1.id <- 0
df$other2.id <- 0

df$other1.id <- ifelse(df$id.in.group == "1" , 2, df$other1.id)
df$other2.id <- ifelse(df$id.in.group == "1" , 3, df$other2.id)

df$other1.id <- ifelse(df$id.in.group == "2" , 1, df$other1.id)
df$other2.id <- ifelse(df$id.in.group == "2" , 3, df$other2.id)

df$other1.id <- ifelse(df$id.in.group == "3" , 1, df$other1.id)
df$other2.id <- ifelse(df$id.in.group == "3" , 2, df$other2.id)

View(df)
```

Given the group number (df$group) and the id of the others in the group (df$other1.id and df$other2.id), I would like to create two further variables showing, for each trial and each subject, the value of the other 2 subjects rather than their relative id.in.group, so as to get the two following columns

```
df$other1.subject<-c("s11","s7","s7","s9","s6","s6","s10","s12","s12","s2","s8","s8","s9","s5","s5","s1","s10","s10","s7","s4","s4","s12","s8","s8", "s3","s5","s5","s11","s12","s12","s6","s1","s1","s2","s4","s4")
df$other2.subject<-c("s3","s3","s11","s4","s4","s9","s1","s1","s10","s5","s5","s2","s6","s6","s9","s3","s3","s1","s2","s2","s7","s11","s11","s12","s9","s9","s3","s10","s10","s11","s7","s7","s6","s8","s8","s2")

View(df)
```

For instance, if trial = 1 and id.in.group = 1 (or alternatively, subject = s7), then other1.subject = s11 while other2.subject = s3. I would like to extract such values for each id.in.group (or each subject) or for each row.

I beg you a pardon if I don't provide any previous attempt but, honestly, I have no clue about how to tackle the problem. I remain open to any further clarification.

Many thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to left join df with itself two times - one for other1, second for other2:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  left_join(
    df %>% 
      select(group, trial, other1.id = id.in.group, other1.subject = subject),
    by = c("group", "trial", "other1.id")
  ) %>% 
  left_join(
    df %>% 
      select(group, trial, other2.id = id.in.group, other2.subject = subject),
    by = c("group", "trial", "other2.id")
  )
```

Comment: The code works smoothly and provides the two columns that I need, I thank you very very much!